# Minimum Thickness of Insulation of a Pipe

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity

We know that there is the critical radius of insulation where heat transfer is maximum at that radius.  [Heat Transfer vs Insulation Thickness](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxcXX.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxcXX.png)

From the graph, we can see that as long as the radius of the insulation is between r1 (Radius of pipe) and r*, the insulation increases the heat transfer, thus for the insulation to be effective, the radius must be greater than r*. I cannot figure out a way to calculate r*. I have tried looking for the answer online, but it seems that every website only focuses on the critical value. They mention the minimum insulation thickness (r*) but they do not include any calculations. Is there a way to represent r* mathematically?

Comment: Are you sure about this?  It doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Although this is definitely a real effect, there's little need to calculate r* during piping design calculations, so it doesn't appear in the usual design handbooks.  With modern insulation materials, by the time you put on even the thinnest standard application you're well outside these radii.  It only really matters with very small radii pipes in a very windy environment. N.B. It can be significant for wires:  The extra radius of their insulation actually helps keep them cool when there's any air space, so this is considered as part of ampacity calculations.

Answer (score 1):

While the full equation for heat transfer through insulation as $r_2$ changes is:
$$q_r = {T- T_\infty\over{{ln\big({r_2\over r_1}\big)}\over 2\pi Lk}+{1\over {h(2\pi r_2L)}}}$$
([ref](http://www.cdeep.iitb.ac.in/webpage_data/nptel/Mechanical/Heat%20and%20Mass%20Transfer/Conduction/Module%202/main/2.6.4.html)), differentiating $q_r$, i.e. $dq_r/dr_2$ gives this equation also found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_insulation) (under 'Insulation of cylinders'), the critical insulation thickness is:
$$r_{cr, cylinder} = {k\over h}$$
this [reference](http://www.cdeep.iitb.ac.in/webpage_data/nptel/Mechanical/Heat%20and%20Mass%20Transfer/Conduction/Module%202/main/2.6.4.html) calculates a reasonable maximum for critical thickness, when $k =0.05W/mK$, and $h = 5W/m^2K$, of $10mm$. The effects of radiation and forced convection both decrease the critical thickness value even further.

The critical thickness value is a good guideline for minimum insulation outer radius.

Comment: This is the answer and it's a good answer. To reach above heat transfer equation we must study *"Analysis of Heat and Mass Transfer"*.